# How can I find the subsets of closest points within a set of points?

Tags: python, algorithm

**Problem**

Say, for example, I am given a set of points like the following:
[image: Original Plot]

I want to find the n points with the closest average distance between each other (assuming I know the distance between all points and the total number of points is divisible by n).

**Case 1:** So going on the example I showed before, let's say n was 3, then I would get something the following with no overlap:

[image: 2 Grouped Points]

**Case 2:** If n was 2 then I should get the following:

[image: 3 Group Plot]

**Question:** Is there any sort of algorithm that could be used to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use Scikit-Learn's KMeans algorithm. With this algorithm you precisely have to set n beforehand, so it completely matches you're problem.

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) is the documentation and some examples so you see how to proceed.

Hope this helps.